# Change URL name in Events and Screens

Tags: events, google-analytics, data-import, web-analytics-tools, google-analytics-4

I am administrator of a Learning Platform, where pages have very random URLs, which makes tracking them in GA4 cumbersome. Is there a method to permanently assign bespoke names to urls?

I tried looking up Google Help and tutorials.

I came across a URL trimming method, about FBCLID utms, but just cutting the url shorter won't make it more recognisable.